# Laravel 8: Check if Record in Database is Empty

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-8

Im trying to test when a record is empty or not. Not sure why this isn't working. user_id is my FK. When there is no record I like it to show that it's empty and when it's added to show it's added. I'm manually adding removing a record to test it.

**Migration**

```
Schema::create('business_dashboards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('business_name');
            $table->string('website');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BusinessDashboard extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'business_name',
        'website',
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function userprofile()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
$businessDashboardUserId = BusinessDashboard::where('user_id', null)->first();

    if ($businessDashboardUserId) {
       dd('Is Null');
    } else {
       dd('Not Null');
    }
```

DB Table
[image]

Comment: Not working how exactly ? What is the outcome of this code ? Also one more thing 
You're trying to get `BusinessDashboard` when the `user_id` is null which is pretty sure it will return nothing.

Comment: Better way to check if something exist in your table is to use `exists` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist).  Example: `if (BusinessDashboard::where('user_id', null)->exists()) { // yes } else { // no }`. But then again you can also use [whereNull](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) instead of `where`. @Ginz77

Comment: what result are you actually expecting as this looks odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `whereNull()` and `count()` for conditional

```
$businessDashboardUserId = BusinessDashboard::whereNull('user_id')->first();

    if (!$businessDashboardUserId->count()) {
       dd('Is Null');
    } else {
       dd('Not Null');
    }
```

Or even nicer

```
if (!BusinessDashboard::whereNull('user_id')->exists()) {
   dd('Is Null');
} else {
   dd('Not Null');
}
```

Comment: Still not giving me the result. Could it be something wrong with the model or migration? I added the other code to the post.